# Docker container time 2 hours behind when TZ=CEST

Tags: docker, timezone, daylight-saving

I try to run a Docker container with the same timezone as my Docker host. The host timezone is `CEST`.

When I run :

```
$ date
Thu Apr 16 11:04:11 CEST 2020
$ docker run -e TZ=CEST debian:buster date
Thu Apr 16 09:04:14 CEST 2020
```

The container is 2 hours behind the host.

On the other hand, if I set `TZ=Europe/Paris`, it works as expected :

```
$ docker run -e TZ=Europe/Paris debian:buster date
Thu Apr 16 11:04:22 CEST 2020
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it appears that `CEST` is not a valid value for `TZ` environment variable. `CEST` is just a displayable version of `CET` when the current date *is* summer.

In fact, if I set `TZ` to an obviously invalid value, it gives :

```
$ TZ=FOO date
Fri Apr 17 14:07:56 FOO 2020
```

Also note that it has nothing to do with Docker.

References :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
- https://www.iana.org/time-zones
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()

Answer (score 4):

The timezone is set by default and you need to change it manually.

There are some options:

Set it in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Using volumes to synchronize with your host:

```
volumes:
- "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
- "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

or

```
docker run -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
```

Finally, set it manually but if you restart the container you lose the configuration:

```
docker run -e TZ=America/New_York ubuntu date
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As you can see, I'm already using `TZ` environment variable to set the timezone. But in the case of `TZ=CEST`, which is the timezone configured on the host, it has unexpected behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood. If you try to configure the TZ with `tzselect` you can not use CEST. So As far I can see there is no possible to use TZ=CEST in Debian 10 to set the TZ. You need to use 'Europe/Madrid' or similar.